# Why does Loader Snaps not work when attaching to a process?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, windbg, gflags

When I configure GFlags to show loader snaps on an image MYEXE.exe and run the executable from windbg I get loader snaps output in the debug window.  But when I use windbg to attach to the process already running I do not, even though I enabled loader snaps before the process was started.  How can I get loader snaps to work when attaching to a process that I do not want to start with windbg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is by-design. What's your scenario? Do you know about `sxe ld`?

Comment: I did not know about sxe ld until now, this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, this is working fine for me. I tested this out using notepad.exe on my 32 bit Win7 box. I can properly see loader snaps both when launching notepad under windbg, as well when attaching to a fresh notepad process afterwards. When attaching to the process, you will have to trigger it to "do something." In my case, once I attached windbg to notepad, I had to click on File->Open.